# Select Link or Checkbox to Display Category Markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am somewhat stuck at trying to tell Javascript to do what I want it to do.

I have an example map http://calwestcultural.com/sgs/backup/example-map.html and I have categories in my spry menu to the left. I would like those categories to be clickable and reveal only markers for that category.

I'd like to:
1. Hide Markers on load
2. When you click on a category (for example "eat" "banks" etc) I'd like ONLY for the markers within that category to show

*if creating a checkbox within the menu makes this easier, i am willing to do that. I am just hung up on this part of my map and need to move on.

CAN ANYONE PLEASE HELP? Something tells me this is an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep markers in separate categories, create an array for each category of marker and use them to store each set of markers. Then do the following:

To hide markers on load, create the markers but leave the marker map property set to `null`:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: null,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
```

To show only the markers in a given category, listen for the event that should trigger display of the markers and then set the markers' map property:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < markerCategoryArray.length; i++ ) {
    markerCategoryArray[i].setMap( map );
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... i tried the first option but it removed all markers even when i clicked on them in my menu (just displays the info window). At the moment, i have no categories as I am hung up on how to create them with the map and functionality i have now. [see my map here](http://calwestcultural.com/sgs/backup/example-map.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got a clue on how to do this from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531781/576) without multiple category arrays. More so, [google maps v3 example linked](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html) there showed the following.

```
var gmarkers = [];
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    icon: gicons[category],
    shadow: iconShadow,
    map: map,
    title: name,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
});
// === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
marker.mycategory = category;                                 
marker.myname = name;
gmarkers.push(marker);
```

Then just filter by the category on the marker as depicted in the exmaple.

```
// == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
function show(category) {
   for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
        gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
      }
   }
   // == check the checkbox ==
   document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
}

// == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
function hide(category) {
   for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
        gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
   }
   // == clear the checkbox ==
   document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
   // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
   infowindow.close();
}
```